# The content type text/xml; charset="utf-8" of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8)

Tags: c#, wcf, http, .net-core

Please note that this question pertains to the .NET Core implementation of WCF Connected Services.

I am porting a regular .NET WCF client over to .NET Core, but I ran into this issue:

```
The content type text/xml; charset="utf-8" of the response message does
not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8).

If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is
implemented properly. The first 1024 bytes of the response were: 
'<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?> [...]
```

The response indeed contains the quotes:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 Ok
content-type: text/xml; charset="utf-8"
```

I never did anything special to handle this in WCF proper. Is this a bug in the .NET Core version, or is it just really specific about the content type (utf-8 vs "utf-8")?

How can I change the expected content type to match the service I'm calling? (I have no control over that, but I can copy and alter the WSDL if needed).

I'm using a svcutil-generated client. (Connected Service)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It would indeed seem that the .NET Core version is more picky about this. In any case, I managed to solve it using a Custom Encoder.

I blatently stole the CustomTextMessageEncoder from  [Github](https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/blob/master/src/System.Private.ServiceModel/tools/IISHostedWcfService/App_code/testhosts/CustomTextMessageEncoder.cs). I added the following method:

```
public override bool IsContentTypeSupported(string contentType)
{
    return true;
}
```

And stole `CustomTextMessageBindingElement` and `CustomTextMessageEncoderFactory` from the same place.

I added them by creating a custom binding (basicBinding is the binding I had before):

```
var customBindingElement = new CustomTextMessageBindingElement("UTF-8", "text/xml", MessageVersion.Soap11);
var binding = new CustomBinding(basicBinding);
binding.Elements.RemoveAt(0);
binding.Elements.Insert(0, customBindingElement);
var client = (T2)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T), binding, address);
```

I use Activator as I generate my proxies dynamically. Just replace with a call to the WCF generated client.

Quite a lot of work for two misplaced quotes :D

Comment: Can you point me to an example of where to add this to my .Net Core project? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: I tried to update my answer to show how I use the 'stolen' classes.

Comment: OMG!!!!!!!!!!!!! That actually works! I was missing the step of...well...all the steps. You're a genius. Thank you so much!

Comment: @crackedcornjimmy: I can relate. Fixing those two stupid quotes took WAAY longer than I had hoped. Glad I could help.

Comment: I was trying to solve this error for days... that help me a lot. thank you!

Comment: Has his been raised as a bug in git hub for this project? or is it even a bug. a lot of old web services break if custom encoder is not implemented

Comment: @shobhonk: Personally, I haven't. It seemed like an incorrect implementation in the service I was calling, but I may be wrong.

Comment: For fellow WCF noddies running into this problem and solution, Troels' code has to be placed into the GetBindingForEndpoint() method of your generated `Reference.cs` file, and in my case (and probably yours) without the Activator line. Good work Troels!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem also. There might be an issue with security-related or content-type format differences. I got over the problem by ignoring ServiceReference bindings. You should directly call with **HttpWebRequest** 
As a sample;

```
  private string GetWebService(string token, int testId, string phone)
    {
        try
        {
            var serviceUrl = "https://test.com/Soap";

            var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(serviceUrl);
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "text/xml";
            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
            {

                var xmlData = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:doc=\"http://test.com\">" +
                "   <soapenv:Header/>" +
                "   <soapenv:Body>" +
                "      <doc:AskForStackOverFlow>" +
                "         <doc:token>" + token + "</doc:token>" +
                "         <doc:testId>" + testId+ "</doc:testId>" +
                "         <doc:phone>" + phone + "</doc:phone>" +
                "         <doc:startTime>" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") + "</doc:startTime>" +
                "      </doc:AskForStackOverFlow>" +
                "   </soapenv:Body>" +
                "</soapenv:Envelope>";

                streamWriter.Write(xmlData);
            }

            var xmlResult = "";
            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                xmlResult = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(xmlResult))
                return "";


            var result = "";
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(xmlResult);
            XmlNodeList nodes = doc.GetElementsByTagName("ns1:AskForStackOverFlowResult");
            foreach (XmlNode item in nodes)
            {
                result = item.InnerText;
            }

            return result;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.Message;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the exact same error after converting a WCF Client to dotnet core.  I have to refactor some.  I replaced my binding code to this.  Note WsBinding isn't native in dotnet core.

https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/1370