# Response content validation failed

Tags: wcf, .net-core, soap, wsdl, .net-standard

I'm rewriting app from .NET framework 4.6.1 to .NET Core 3.1.
One library needs to communicate with Soap service. Basically everything works, except response reading.

It looks that the problem is with charset, expected is **charset="utf-8"** received **charset=utf-8**.

Does someone have any idea how to adjust it on client side?

Best regards
Fabian

```
System.ServiceModel.ProtocolException: The content type text/xml; charset="utf-8" of the response message does not match the content type of the binding (text/xml; charset=utf-8). If using a custom encoder, be sure that the IsContentTypeSupported method is implemented properly. The first 518 bytes of the response were: '<?xml version="1.0" ?><S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><S:Body><ns2:generatePackagesNumbersV2Response xmlns:ns2="http://dpdservices.dpd.com.pl/"><return xmlns=""><Status>OK</Status><SessionId>2722911</SessionId><Packages><Package><Status>OK</Status><PackageId>1264106</PackageId><Parcels><Parcel><Status>OK</Status><ParcelId>1758645</ParcelId><Waybill>0000000831731Q</Waybill></Parcel></Parcels></Package></Packages></return></ns2:generatePackagesNumbersV2Response></S:Body></S:Envelope>'.
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpResponseMessageHelper.ValidateContentTypeAsync()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpResponseMessageHelper.ParseIncomingResponse(TimeoutHelper timeoutHelper)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpClientRequestChannel.HttpClientChannelAsyncRequest.ReceiveReplyAsync(TimeoutHelper timeoutHelper)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.RequestAsync(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.RequestAsyncInternal(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.Runtime.TaskHelpers.WaitForCompletionNoSpin[TResult](Task`1 task)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.RequestChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(MethodCall methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(MethodInfo targetMethod, Object[] args)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Reflection.DispatchProxyGenerator.Invoke(Object[] args)
   at generatedProxy_1.generatePackagesNumbersV2(generatePackagesNumbersV2Request )
   at ServiceReference2.DPDPackageObjServicesClient.generatePackagesNumbersV2(generatePackagesNumbersV2Request request) in C:\Users\fabia\Repos\DocFlowPlatformCore.Server\ClassLibrary1\Connected Services\ServiceReference2\Reference.cs:line 9646
   at Scodes.ShippingProvider.Dpd.DpdProvider2.Create(Shipment shipment) in C:\Users\fabia\Repos\DocFlowPlatformCore.Server\ClassLibrary1\Class1.cs:line 67
```

Comment: What bindings did you use? The bindings supported by core are limited.

Comment: Hi I'm using basic http binding. Finally I found simillar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41684342/the-content-type-text-xml-charset-utf-8-of-the-response-message-does-not-matc)
but after applying it, server have problem with reading my request, so basically I've decided to implement my own client and using HttpWebRequests

Comment: Did HttpWebRequests help you solve the problem?

Comment: Basically yes, but a lot of additional work to implement communication is needed.